# How can I show distance indicators along a line feature in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, line, distance

I am preparing a map of a 120 km long walking trail in QGIS 2.18 for publication (printing). I have a shapefile (line feature) showing the walking trail. I want to be able to show distance indicators along the trail route at 2km intervals i.e. how far a certain point is from the start & finish of the walking trail. Is there a geoprocessing tool or plugin that I can use to do this?

Comment: Welcome to GSE ! With a plugin, look at QChainage : http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qchainage/

Answer (score 2):

Try the "points along geometry" tool from the Processing toolbox.